# flutter project - INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when trying to install on device

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, adb

I am getting this kind of error in vs code from past 1 day and implemented all possible results
but, I dint get any solution plz help me to get rid of this

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install F:\flutter firebase\authenticationapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Error launching application on vivo 1819
```

Comment: Reenable USB debugging on the device and restart.

Comment: `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` means the device does not support the binaries of the app. Most likely the device supportes only 32bit (ARMv7) and the project is compiled for 64bit only (ARMv8).